# Why is HTMLEntity &lt; being removed when using "bypassSecurityTrustHtml"?

Tags: angular

I have a place in my app where i want to display strings i got from user by using innerHTML.

Some of the strings may be something like `'a<b'`. angular default sanitizes this and displays only `a`.

I used a pipe with "bypassSecurityTrustHtml" and is still shows me only the "a".

This is a simplified example:

```
<span [innerHTML]="'a&lt;b' | displayAll"></span>
```

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Pipe({
    name: 'displayAll'
})
export class DisplayAll implements PipeTransform {
    constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) { }
    transform(str: string) {
       return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(str);
    }
}
```

Should say that if it is typed in with spaces, this way:

```
<span [innerHTML]="'a &lt; b' | displayAll"></span>
```

it dose work, but the content is from (safe) users and i can't restrict them to type only this way. If i don't have a choice i will just replace "<" by " < ".

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is that `&lt;` is being converted to `<` before being passed into your pipe. So, the pipe gets `a<b` and `<b` is getting removed as it is a malformed opening tag.

If the content is truly safe, and from users, then it would be ideal to get the data via an api call and bind it like:

```html
<span [innerHTML]="myData | displayAll"></span>
OR
<span [innerHTML]="(getData() | async) | displayAll"></span>
```

Then the data should be passed directly to the pipe without being transformed.

Or you could modify your pipe to turn `<` back into a html entity:

```js
this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(str.replace(/[\u00A0-\u9999<>\&]/g, i => `&#${i.charCodeAt(0)};`));
```

But then legit HTML tags won't be rendered.